# PyQt4 | handling 'X' - exit button in QDialog

Tags: python, pyqt, exit, qdialog

For few weeks I have been coding a plugin to some well known GIS free software (QGIS). And I've got a little problem with it.

My the plugin scheme looks like this:

```
.......
class DisplayedWindow(object):
        
        def __init__(self):
            #JANEK Main dialog
            self.window_plugin = QtGui.QDialog()
            self.window_plugin.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)
            self.window_plugin.setGeometry(150, 150, 750, 675)
            self.window_plugin.setWindowTitle('the plugin')
            self.window_plugin.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint|Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint) 
            
            ............. (GUI, functions, etc.).......
            
def run(self):

    dis_win = self.DisplayedWindow()
    if dis_win.window_plugin.exec_():
        pass
```

I know that it is not build as it should be, but I'm begginer. What's fine is that the plugin works really nice, and I'm too far gone within coding it to change now the whole structure of the program.

What I'm looking for (and can't find so far) is a way to handle X-exit red button, so the user could be asked before closing the window if he/she doesen't want to save changes etc.

I need something like `self.X_close_button.clicked.connect(lambda: closing_stuff())`

Does anyone know how to recieve it? Or any other way in such a dialog to control what happens after somebody closes the window (self.window_plugin)?

Answer (score 1):

Extend `QDialog` and override its `closeEvent()` method :

```
class GISDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GISDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setGeometry(150,150,750,750)
        self.window_plugin.setWindowTitle('the plugin')
        # other intitialization

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
            "Do you want to save?", QMessageBox.Yes, QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()
```

then, when you are ready to use it:

```
dialog = GISDialog()
if dialog.exec():
    pass  # do stuff on success
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I still have a problem. The main window is an object, not a class. How can I "replace" this closeEvent() methon then?

i tried something like, 
self.window_plugin.closeEvent() = closeEvent()
but it causes error

Comment: What if `QDialog`  is a subclass of `QMainWindow`? How do I say that I want to override the `closeEvent` method of `QDialog` and not of `QMainWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple example for you. There is the whole code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
class Create_Dialog_Box(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        super(Create_Dialog_Box, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(100,100,500,200)
    def closeEvent(self,event):
        quit_msg = "Are you sure you want to exit the dialog?"
        reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message', 
                        quit_msg, QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QtGui.QWidget()
w.setGeometry(100,100,200,50)

d = Create_Dialog_Box(w)

b = QtGui.QPushButton(w)
b.setText("Click Me!")
b.move(50,20)
b.clicked.connect(d.show)


w.setWindowTitle("PyQt")
w.show()
print("End")
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When you try to exit the dialog it prompt as shown the the following image:

[image]

Hope it Helps.